# jquery chosen clone not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have used [jquery choosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to select single and multiple options. So I made my markup like this

```
<div class="content">
      <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div>
          <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="15">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option selected>American Black Bear</option>
            <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
            <option>Brown Bear</option>
            <option>Giant Panda</option>
            <option>Sloth Bear</option>
            <option>Sun Bear</option>
            <option>Polar Bear</option>
            <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="16">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>American Black Bear</option>
            <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
            <option>Brown Bear</option>
            <option selected>Giant Panda</option>
            <option>Sloth Bear</option>
            <option>Sun Bear</option>
            <option>Polar Bear</option>
            <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-new">Add New</button>
```

I wanted to clone this means when I will click on add new button then another row will be append. So for that I made my jquery like this

```
     jQuery('.add-new').click(function() {
      var parent = jQuery('div.content').last();
      parent.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
  });
```

This one is doing clone but the selection and dropdown for the second row(clonned) is not working. Whenever I am doing click on the select options it is working on the parent. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this?

When I am doing manually copy the entire div again it is working without any issue. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I have created JSFiddle with your code, http://jsfiddle.net/6v91w563/ and to me it is working as you are expecting, am i misunderstanding you?

Comment: @JavaKB yes there are some jquery file should be included. You can see the demo of the plugin. There you can see jQuery code has been used in the file

Comment: Try running `$('div.content').chosen()` after adding second div.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin nope its not working....

Comment: @NewUser, have you checked my answer? Did it help? If yes, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your script part a little:

```
var clone = $('div.content').clone(true);
$('div.content select').chosen();

jQuery('.add-new').click(function() {
    var parent = jQuery('div.content').last();
     clone.clone(true).insertAfter(parent); 
     $('div.content:last select').chosen();
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6v91w563/1/). So basically, I remember `div.content` **before** any chosen logic. Then I just use this copy to add new contents.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.